# Does getting an unaccept change the "accept don't count towards the max" calculation?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, unaccepted-answer

Today (2/5/15) I am currently being capped at 200 rep (several upvotes have not counted). Since I have one accepted answer, I would normally expect to max out at 215, not 200, as reputation from accepts doesn't count against the cap.

However, for some reason, an asker *unaccepted* a previous day's answer today, leaving me at 1 accept and 1 unaccept for the day (though the unaccept wasn't accepted today)

Is this causing my cap to not be what I expect? Is this expected behavior, or a bug?

Comment: Note that while I would like the 15 rep, I'm more interested in discovering how the system works/if it is broken. Obviously I don't have all that much to complain about :)

Comment: This is just the confusing way that the events get mixed together in the totals. See [Separate and visually indicate reversed events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like accepts, *unaccepts* do not count towards the cap either. You just lose the 15 points, the cap calculation is unchanged and unaffected.

So you got 200 points from upvotes (capped), 15 points from the accept, and -15 points from the unaccept. Your net reputation change is then 200 (200 + 15 - 15).

Now, if someone *undid a normal upvote vote*, you'd lose 10 points from the capped reputation, after which subsequent normal upvote would then count again until you once again hit that cap. The same would apply to a downvote on one of your posts, or if you downvoted someone else's answer. You'd lose some reputation, and the next upvote would count until you are at the maximum 200 points for the again.

Comment: I see, the unaccept isn't a -15 for cap purposes. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: exactly. Why would accepts not count towards the cap but unaccepts would? If that were so you'd be able to cheat the cap: have someone accept, then when capped have them unaccept, get extra points from upvotes, get the accept again, etc.

Comment: @pnuts: exactly; if you are anywhere between 191 and 199 points from post votes (up and down), that next upvote takes you to 200 and no further.